# Avoid duplicate storage of map key

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

Let's say I have a `std::map<std::string, T>` (or `unordered_map`) and I want to access the key from an iterator/reference/pointer to the content.

Is there a way to do that without having two copies of the `std::string` key (one owned by the map, one inside the content object)?  Can one be a reference to the other?

Comment: How about using a `std::set<T,C>` where `C` compares the string stored in `T`?

Comment: @Daniel: But then I'd need to provide an entire `T` object for lookup, and not just a `std::string`, right?  Or can `C` be overloaded to compare `T` to `T` and also `T` to `std::string`?

Comment: Ahh, I see that C++14 will add a templated `find` member to search on any type that can compare with `T`.

Comment: Maybe a dummy `T` used for such purposes could work (where you just set the string). But I can see that it might become akward, depending on what `T` is.

Comment: Linear search seems to be the only solution.

Comment: By "reference to the content" do you mean "reference to a object of the mapped type"? There's generally no reason why such an object should appear as the mapped element of any map entry, or why it should be unique - or do you mean "reference to an object that is the mapped element of an element of the map"?

Comment: How about boost multi_index http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: @KerrekSB: By "reference to the content" I mean `T& r = the_map[key];` (or a pointer), and later on I want to find out from `r` what its key value is.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There is a difference between *iterator* and reference/pointer to the content. The *iterators* for associative containers refer to the `std::pair<const Key,value>` (i.e. `Container::value_type`, so in that case nothing needs to be done.

Comment: @David: Yes, but I just noticed the iterators get invalidated often.  Do you know if the rule "Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets
elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements." means that references to the `std::pair` stay valid, or only to the `value_type`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The invalidation is due to ordering and buckets and what not (for unordered, for `std::map` iterators don't invalidate that often), but if you maintain a pointer/reference to the `value_type` that won't change.

Comment: @David: Ack, I said `value_type` when I meant `mapped_type`.  References to `value_type` stay valid just like references to `mapped_type`?  It isn't clear to me which "pointers or references to elements" actually means.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Even if you interpret the standard as only guaranteed the value type (i.e. second argument to the template), it is impossible to guarantee that the *value* is pinned in memory and the `value_type` is not (considering that `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key,Value>`, if `value_type::second` does not move, then `value_type` does not move either.

Comment: @David: Ahh, I hadn't considered that the `Value` is stored directly within the `pair`'s memory block.  Of course you are right.

Comment: @BenVoigt: An "element" is a thing of type `value_type`, so that's the entire pair. Elements may get moved around, but their internal integrity remains.

Answer (score 3):

Would you consider using boost::bimap? Below is a simple example:

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <string>
struct Person
{
    Person()
    {}
    Person(const std::string& f, const std::string& l, int a) : first(f), last(l), age(a)
    {}
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    int age;
};

bool operator <(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs)
{
    if(lhs.last < rhs.last)
        return true;
    return false;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Person& p)
{
    os << "First Name: " << p.first << " Last Name: " << p.last << " Age: " << p.age;
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    typedef boost::bimap<std::string, Person> people;
    typedef people::value_type value;

    people m;
    m.insert(value("12345",Person("fred", "rabbit", 10)));
    m.insert(value("67890",Person("benjamin", "bunny", 12)));

    Person p = m.left.at("12345");
    std::cout << "Person with serial no. 12345 is: " << p << "\n";
    std::cout << "Serial number of " << p << " is: " << m.right.at(p) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: That could work, but I feel like it's designed for the case where you only have a copy of the `mapped_type` element, probably synthesized, without metadata such as a direct pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they made this hard is because it's dangerous.  You have to GUARANTEE that none of the `std::string` members being key'd off of will never change value, or the whole map becomes invalidated.  Interesting, the first solution that comes to mind appears insanely hackish, and *looks* like UB, but I believe I very carefully skirt the UB.

```
struct key_type {
    mutable const char* ptr;    
};
bool operator<(const key_type& lhs, const key_type& rhs)
{return strcmp(lhs.ptr, rhs.ptr)<0;}

struct person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};
person& people_map_get(std::map<key_type, person>& map, const char* name) {
    auto it = map.insert(name, person{name}).first; //grab, possibly insert
    if->first.ptr = it->second.name.c_str(); //in case of insert, fix ptr
    return it->second;
}
person& people_map_assign(std::map<key_type, person>& map, person p) {
    auto pair = map.insert(name, p); //grab, possibly insert
    auto it = pair.first;       
    if (pair.second == false) 
        it->second = std::move(p);
    if->first.ptr = it->second.name.c_str(); //ptr probably invalidated, so update it
    return it->second;
}

int main() {
    std::map<key_type, person> people;
    people_map_assign(people, person{"ted"});
    person frank = people_map_get(people, "frank");
}
```

As I hope is clear, this is *crazy* close to UB, and very much not recommended.  Basically, during an insert/find, the key points at your temporary object or input string, and then as soon as the object is inserted/found, the key is changed to point at the value contained in the string member, and as long as you never do anything that would invalidate the return value of `.c_str()` on any contained `person` object, everything just barely works.  I think.

Comment: As dribeas pointed out, I can keep a `std::pair<const std::string, T>*` and have access to both.  Otherwise, as dribeas explained, the key has a fixed memory location, so the content could store a pointer to that key.  I think that would be much less crazy.

Comment: I don't think you can store that in `T`, since `T` would be incomplete at the point of declaration, and `pair` requires it to be complete.  No wait, because a pointer to `pair` might not require it.... I'm not sure if that works or not.  It might.

Comment: I definitely can keep a `const std::string*` in `T`.  I see your point about putting the `value_type*` or iterator inside another element, but I don't need `std::pair` to be complete there, since I'm just storing a pointer.

Comment: Excellent!  That's superior to my answer, other than the fact a `T` isn't "complete" until after it's in the map.

Comment: Right, `std::pair` doesn't seem to have any constructor that provides the `second` subobject constructor with a reference to `first`, so a pointer has to be stored post-construction.

Comment: Behold: [extreme self-referential craziness](http://ideone.com/RGDBu8).  I'm pretty sure it's legal and completely well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create two objects:

```
std::set<std::string> wordSet;
std::map<std::string*, T> yourMap;
```

T must contain pointer to std::string, and yourMap needs custom comparator. Additionally you can wrap all these in some class.

Answer (score -1):

Both can be a reference to the same value.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct xx { std::string mykey; int value; };

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string                     key1("the-key");
    std::map<std::string, xx>       map;

    map[key1].mykey = key1;
    map[key1].value = 13;

    std::string &lookup_key = map[key1].mykey;

    printf("%d\n", map[lookup_key].value);
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  If I have `auto& content = map[key1];`, I need to be able to get from `content` to `key1` again.  One way is to put a copy of the key inside of the content type.  I'm asking if there's a way to avoid having a copy.

Comment: Oh, that clarifies it.  The only way would be to walk the entire collection to find the content with the same address.  Or keep a second collection that gives the map either by address, or some other content of T.

Comment: By the way, it's this that lead me to answer as I did: "Can one be a reference to the other?"